# On really old Ubuntu 6.06 - How to upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I'm on an old Ubuntu version (Ubuntu 6.06.2 LTS Server) which isn't really supported any more. So the automatic updates don't work. I have ISPConfig installed to manage a few web sites.

What's the best course of action? I'd like to upgrade to something current, but I can't figure out how to go about doing this, given that the apt-get scripts don't really work any longer.

Comment: is there a particular reason you can't do a clean install with a newer (relative to 6.06) version? I assume you're also running older hardware, so perhaps try 8.04 LTS which has it's end of life in April 2013.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backing up your data and doing a fresh install would be by far the easiest option, I'm afraid

Comment: Yes I think so too, because *if* you get the normal upgrade path working, I'll have to go through all versions since which is a lot of work. A lot of packages have changed over time and you'll probably see a lot upgrading issues that you need to solve. Make a good backup of your system. In this case I'd advise to create an image backup of the whole system disk, including boot sector. Also make sure you can access configuration files from your backup, to check how you had things set up on your 6.06 install.

Comment: When you say "clean install" you mean erase everything on the hard drive and start over, right? The reason I'd like to avoid that is because I have content on that site; it would take a long time to get it all working again.

Comment: OK, I found something that worked for me. The main driver for me upgrading was to get PHP 5.2. I found this link, which uses the Hardy Heron sources: http://blog.admoolabs.com/install-php-52-ubuntu-dapper/

Comment: Well, if we're talking about a VPS which hosts a website - what you usually do is rent a second one with a new OS on it, transfer all the data, configure and test everything and then just modify DNS to point to the new IP. Then you just wipe the old box clean. Just FYI when you finally decide to upgrade... upgrading in-place would result in hours of downtime.

Answer (score 0):

add the old version repos, upgrade to 8.04 lts, add the old version repos again, upgrade to 10.04 lts, add the old version repos, upgrade to 12.04 lts, add the old version repos again, upgrade to 14.04 lts,add the old version repos, upgrade to 16.04 lts, upgrade to 18.04 lts, upgrade to 20.04 lts. done.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, could you please explain the steps you mean by "add the old version repos", and "upgrade to 8.04 lts" in more detail.

Comment: switch from the deafult repos to oldreleases.ubuntu.com repos

Comment: And Upgrade to The Newer Version Via a Thingie that will show up.