# Is it posible to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 from Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04, 14.04

I have 2 PCs (works as a LAMP servers) with

- 10.04.4 LTS
- 12.04.2 LTS

And I want to upgrade to the last LTS (14.04).

I don't want to lose my data (unfortunately I don't have space to copy the information)

Can I upgrade the version without lost my LAMP data?

Comment: You can upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 to 14.04 but that would use a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: I would suggest separating your Home into a separate partition and then perform a clean install of 14.04 using the advanced settings and selecting the home partition not to be wiped. Then you will just have to install your apps again but all their settings will be remember. If you search for "Partitioning / Home / Moving" you will find the instructions on how to do this. I did it and it's easy to do. Take a backup of your system first though.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/131259/on-really-old-ubuntu-6-06-how-to-upgrade